# Animate CSS Letter spacing with direction

Tags: css, css-transitions

My Plan: 
To have some words aligned to the right of the screen with a lot of letter spacing.
When these words are hovered over, the letter spacing reduces. 
**BUT**, when the letter spacing is reduced, the text must still be aligned to the right i.e.

```
                                                              H  E  L  L  O
                                                              W  O  R  L  D
// When hovered -->
                                                                      HELLO
                                                                      WORLD
```

So the last letters in each word have a fixed position.

So far: https://jsfiddle.net/ogoo77h8/1/#&togetherjs=QjBe1mjmJe

When I tried the last letters in each word move.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without modifying the HTML:

https://jsfiddle.net/16wgkemj/

It basically just positions the `<p>` element right (instead of left) then balances out the letter spacing of the last letter with a margin.

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    right: 0%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
}

.hello,
.world {
    -webkit-transition: letter-spacing 2s ease, margin-right 2s ease;
    transition: letter-spacing 2s ease, margin-right 2s ease;
    display:block;
    margin-right:0px;

}

.hello:hover,
.world:hover {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little html and css update can solve the issue.

try this

```
<p class="title">
  <span class="hello">HELL<span>O</span></span>
  <span class="world">WORL<span>D</span></span>
</p>
```

add css

```
.hello span,
.world span{
   letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm just trying to apply it to my personal project because this code currently forces the text to the right edge and remove all posititioning. But your idea of spanning the last letters has given me an idea so I'm just trying it out... Hopefully it works